# Finding 'Next Available' Key in a dictionary or related collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, collections

I want to write an linq extension (or a custom dictionary, sorted list list or whatever solution is best) that will allow me to add a value to a collection with its key being the 'next available' one.

For example:

```
int CreatedKey = IncrementDictionary.AddNext(myCustomer);
```

If the currently existing keys are as follows:

```
1
2
8
4
3
```

Then it would add the myCustomer into the dictionary with a key of 5 and it would return that key.

What do you think?

Comment: I think it's not clear what the question is. I also don't think this would make a particularly useful data structure, as the object reference or a combination of hashcode/equality methods is sufficient to identify the object.

Comment: Hi William, it looks like your question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  You'll find a much better response rate on that site, as it is fully intended for this type of question.

Comment: @DoctaJonez: There's not a lot of code in the question to review...

Comment: @dtb but the OP is asking for people to appraise (or review) his idea, there's no question here, he's just asking for a review

Comment: @DoctaJonez: Which idea? The questions looks to me like the OP is asking for code that satisfies his requirements.

Comment: @dtb it reads as "here's what I'm doing, what do you think?".  Sounds like a review question to me

Comment: @DoctaJonez: So I guess the answer should be "Yes, your method call looks fine. Go ahead and implement the method." then :-)

Comment: @DoctorJones It's not code review. Dictionary.AddNext doesn't exist. The person is asking for how to implement something that does this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319) with Extension method for Adding to next automatically retrieved key.

Assuming Data structure be any object, with numeric key,

Following is ExtensionMethod for SortedList

```
public static class SortedListExtensions
{
    ///Add item to sortedList (numeric key) to next available key item, and return key
    public static int AddNext<T>(this SortedList<int, T> sortedList, T item)
    {
        int key = 1; // Make it 0 to start from Zero based index
        int count = sortedList.Count;

        int counter=0;
        do
        {
            if (count == 0) break;
            int nextKeyInList = sortedList.Keys[counter++];

            if (key != nextKeyInList) break;

            key = nextKeyInList +1;

            if (count == 1 || counter == count  ) break;


            if (key != sortedList.Keys[counter])
                break;

        } while (true);

        sortedList.Add(key, item);
        return key;
    }

}
```

It can be used like following

```
  SortedList<int, string> x = new SortedList<int, string>();

        x.Add(4, "BCD");
        x.Add(6, "BCD");

        x.AddNext("a");
        x.AddNext("b");
        x.AddNext("c");
        x.AddNext("d");
        x.AddNext("e");

        foreach (var item in x)
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " " + item.Value);
```

The output is

```
        1 a
        2 b
        3 c
        4 BCD
        5 d
        6 BCD
        7 e
```

You can use Dictionary, or any other data structure. In that case Double loop will be required. In case of SortedList, one loop is saved while searching key. This loop is internally used by [`SortedList.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132330) function using BinarySearch Algorithm.

Binary search is faster than looping all elements (for larger size data).

Comment: A Dictionary does not require an additional loop because it uses a hash table.

Answer (score 7):

```
public static int AddNext(this Dictionary<int, string> dict)
{
    int min = dict.Keys.Min();
    int max = dict.Keys.Max();

    return Enumerable.Range(min, max-min).Except(dict.Keys).First();   
}
```

Use it as

```
int result = new Dictionary<int, string>(){ {1, "a"}, {2, "a"}, 
                                            {8, "a"}, {4, "a"}, 
                                                      {3, "a"}}.AddNext();
```

Here `result` comes to be 5.

Comment: Wow +1 for you NikHil :) you hit the answer with 1 line :)

Comment: Another great example of a [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm)

Comment: @dtb: I know it but how does that apply here? Could you explain

Comment: @dtb why do you always keep talking about that whoever schlemiel here :).. Is he your college professor?

Comment: With every key you insert into the dictionary, you have to do a bit more work when finding the next key. This is very inefficient. The problem should be solved using an appropriate data structure, not with brute force.

Comment: @dtb I think he is asking for the brute force. not for your data structure.

Comment: This does not work in my case, having either an empty Dictonary or one with only one element.

For an empty one i am getting a InvalidOperationException at the dict.Keys.Min() call.

For a dict with one element im getting the same exception on the Except-call because the Range is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Here was my solution shorter than the first but you could have an idea from it.

```
        Dictionary<int, string> x = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        x.Add(1, "a");
        x.Add(2, "a");
        x.Add(3, "a");
        x.Add(4, "a");
        x.Add(8, "a");
        Console.WriteLine((x.Keys.Where(k => !x.Keys.Contains(k + 1)).Min() + 1).ToString());
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [Schlemiel the Painter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm)?

Comment: @dtb yes ;) thanks for the help :) though my answer was really uhmm :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this (it obviously can contains only 1000 elements)? There can be many other solutions, but it's hard to tell what you exactly want to do. Anyway this could be a starting point.

```
public class IncrementDictionary : Dictionary<int, object>
{
    private bool[] usedKeys = new bool[1000];

    public new void Add(int key, object value)
    {
        base.Add(key, value);
        usedKeys[key] = true;
    }

    public new void Clear()
    {
        base.Clear();
        usedKeys = new bool[1000];
    }

    public new object this[int key] 
    {
        get
        {
            return base[key];
        }
        set
        {
            base[key] = value;
            usedKeys[key] = true;
        }
    }

    public new bool Remove(int key)
    {
        usedKeys[key] = false;
        return base.Remove(key);
    }

    public int AddNext(object anObj)
    {
        int newKey = -1;
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
            if (!usedKeys[i])
            {
                newKey = i;
                break;
            }
        if (newKey > 0)
            this.Add(newKey, anObj);
        return newKey;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... it's an old question, but I'd like to answer.

Nikhil Agrawal's code might be improved considering that, if you have an empty collection, you must specify what is your minimum value. So the code becomes:

```
 public static int FirstFree(Dictionary<int, Guid> dict, int minumum)
    {
        int min = dict.Count == 0
            ? minumum                       //use passed minimum if needed
            : dict.Keys.Min();              //use real minimum
        int max = dict.Count > 1
            ? dict.Keys.Max() + 2           //two steps away from maximum, avoids exceptions
            : min + 2;                      //emulate data presence
        return Enumerable.Range(min, max).Except(dict.Keys).First();
    }
```

But if you work in a defined range you should also know if you have space to store values. This can be the way:

```
public static int? FirstFree(Dictionary<int, Guid> dict, int min, int max)
    {
        if (max <= min)
            throw new Exception($"Specified range is invalid (must be max > min)");
        if (max - min + 1 == dict.Count)
            //no space left
            return null;
        return Enumerable.Range(min, max).Except(dict.Keys).First();
    }
```

If you don't like nullable-int you can check if result is the minimum admitted.
Obviously it doesn't work if you specify min=int.MinValue, I know, but in this case the issue is the huge collection created by this method!

```
public static int FirstFree(Dictionary<int, Guid> dict, int min, int max)
    {
        if (max <= min)
            throw new Exception($"Specified range is invalid (must be max > min)");
        if (max - min + 1 == dict.Count)
            //no space left
            return int.MinValue;
        return Enumerable.Range(min, max).Except(dict.Keys).First();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually ran into a weird need to do this. This solution is faster and more straightforward than any of the other answers.

```
public static void AddNext<T>(this IDictionary<int, T> dict, T item, int startIndex = 0, int maxIndex = Int32.MaxValue)
{
    for (int i = startIndex; i < maxIndex; i++)
    {
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(i))
        {
            dict[i] = item;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this and two other answers here using Stopwatch and a collection with 11 million GUID strings with a hole at the 10m index.

Mine took **80ms**.

Adding a check to include existing keys with a null value comes in at **152ms**.

Tilak's (accepted answer) took **256ms**. This answer uses a SortedList, but the question was for a Dictionary which implies sorting is not required.

Nikhil's (most upvotes) took **709ms**. Also it throws an exception if there are no "holes" and the next available index is at the end.

A commenter implied that there are better data structures for this use case but doesn't mention which ones. Would love to learn more.